# How to use keypress down with buttons in it?

Tags: vb.net

I found my problem whenever I put buttons in my design the keypress down dont work is there a way to make it work even with buttons in the design?
sample code:

```
If e.KeyValue = Keys.P Then
MsgBox("adadddada")
End If


Private Sub Game_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
     ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

 If e.KeyValue = Keys.Down Then
```

> ```
>          If (RArrowDown.Top <= ArrowDown.Top + ArrowDown.Height) And RArrowDown.Visible = True Then
>             offset_1 = RArrowDown.Top - ArrowDown.Top
>             Select Case offset_1
>
>                 Case -10 To 15
>                     'perfect
>                     TimerMain.Enabled = False
>                     Hit += 1
>                     Score += 20
>                     RArrowDown.Visible = False
>                     Perfect.Visible = True
>                     TimerPerfect.Enabled = True
>                     GPerfect += 1
>                     Combo_Counter += 1
>                     RandomTime_1.Enabled = True
>
>                 Case 16 To 50
>                     'good
>                     TimerMain.Enabled = False
>                     Hit += 1
>                     Score += 10
>                     RArrowDown.Visible = False
>                     Good.Visible = True
>                     TimerGood.Enabled = True
>                     GGood += 1
>                     Combo_Counter += 1
>                     RandomTime_1.Enabled = True
>
>                 Case -30 To -11
>                     'good
>                     TimerMain.Enabled = False
>                     Hit += 1
>                     Score += 10
>                     RArrowDown.Visible = False
>                     Good.Visible = True
>                     TimerGood.Enabled = True
>                     GGood += 1
>                     Combo_Counter += 1
>                     RandomTime_1.Enabled = True
>
>             End Select
>         End If
>     End If end sub
> ```

Comment: Can you post some more of the code so we can tell what is capturing the button presses (textbox, form, etc)?

Comment: please expand that snippet to show where that code resides

Comment: @LeftyCoder Like that?

Comment: There must be something else you're doing wrong.  with the form's KeyPreview set to true it traps the keydown event regardless of the controls in the form.

Comment: @tinstaafl Hi I tried making a new application without any code in very clean I tried this if this works If e.KeyValue = Keys.P Then
MsgBox("adadddada")
End If it works after that I added a button and it didnt work

Comment: no - we need to know which event.  you seem to be confusing KeyPress, KeyDown and maybe the Form KeyPreview event.  we need to see this part: `Private Sub XXXXX_KeyPress(ByVal sender...`

Comment: no, as @Plutonix said, we need to know which event from which object you are handling.

Comment: @Plutonix you mean private sub like that?

Comment: @LeftyCoder you mean private sub like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have any controls on your form that can receive a Key Event the Form will Handle it, but as soon as you add a control, it is up to the Focused control to handle the Key Event unless you set the [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) Form Property to True, then the Form will respond to you Key Events again.

From above Link:

> When this property is set to true, the form will receive all KeyPress, KeyDown, and KeyUp events. After the form's event handlers have completed processing the keystroke, the keystroke is then assigned to the control with focus. For example, if the KeyPreview property is set to true and the currently selected control is a TextBox, after the keystroke is handled by the event handlers of the form the TextBox control will receive the key that was pressed. To handle keyboard events only at the form level and not allow controls to receive keyboard events, set the KeyPressEventArgs.Handled property in your form's KeyPress event handler to true.
>
> You can use this property to process most keystrokes in your application and either handle the keystroke or call the appropriate control to handle the keystroke. For example, when an application uses function keys, you might want to process the keystrokes at the form level rather than writing code for each control that might receive keystroke events.

Comment: How can i set this keypreview?

Comment: Select your form in the designer use F4 to select the properties panel in Visual Studio. you will find it in there.